# Add a margin to bootstrap grid without increase size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a space around the border of a bootstrap grid but when I do it shifts everything and moves the elements to the next line. I tried using :after as well and it did not take.  How can I add a space around the border without breaking the grid?

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 section1a sectionstyle">
  <small>first</small>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
    </div>
  <a class="btn btn-success btn-primary btn-block buttoncenter" href="#" role="button">Submit!</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 section1a sectionstyle">
  <small>first</small>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
    </div>
  <a class="btn btn-success btn-primary btn-block buttoncenter" href="#" role="button">Submit!</a>
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 section1a sectionstyle">
  <small>first</small>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
    </div>
  <a class="btn btn-success btn-primary btn-block buttoncenter" href="#" role="button">Submit!</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sectionstyle {
  position : relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: tan;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  //margin:1px;
}
.sectionstyle:after {
  margin:5px;
}
```

JSBIN

http://jsbin.com/xicezopiqe/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Bootstrap uses padding not margin for gutters. Are you talking about making the gutters bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would use elements inside the`.col-sm-4` divs....

See [this updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xitizaweli/1/edit?html,css,output)

I formatted it more like how bootstrap grids are typically used. If you really need it without the gutters, Naeems answer provides a good option.

HTH,

-Ted

Comment: Should have thought of putting the div in the grid div. Thanks for setting me straight!

Answer (score 1):

see this: http://jsbin.com/tipasehalu/1/

You can set a box-shadow inset as a border, and make color of border look white, so feels like a gap between elements

```
.sectionstyle {
    position : relative;
    border: 1px solid #fff; // treated as a gap(margin)
    border-radius: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    background-color: tan;
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px grey;  // traeted as a border
    box-sizing: border-box;
    //margin:1px;
}
.sectionstyle:after {
  margin:5px;
}
```

Well its not actually a margin(gap), but really works like it.